# How to embed HTML <tag> that is returned in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

In short:

The `response` to an `AJAX` call returns 2 `HTML` elements, `script` and `div`, which are stored in `JSON` format. The `response` is structured like this:

```
Object { script : "<script>...</script>", div : "<div></div>" }
```

`response` contains the objects in `JSON` that I need to embed. How can I do this? My code:

```
<body>
<script type=text/javascript>
     $.ajax({
        url: "my.url",
        type: "GET",
          datatype: "json",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(response){
          // Code that embeds script and div in to the body of the document
        }
     });
</script>
```

---

A bit more detail:

`div` contains 3 graphs that are referenced from the `script` element. Both of them are returned from a `python` script that runs `bokeh`. Everything else works fine, I am just new to `HTML` and `javascript` and that is why I don't know how to embed the tags from the `JSON` to the html body.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: Unlike [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637762/returning-the-html-from-ajax-call), I am asking specific help on how to embed the returned `JSON` without any div parameters to `AJAX` function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning the html from .ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637762/returning-the-html-from-ajax-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse your JSON to an object via the [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function

```
<body>
<script type=text/javascript>
     $.ajax({
        url: "my.url",
        type: "GET",
          datatype: "json", 
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(response){

          // Parse to object
          var object_response = JSON.parse(response);

          // Access object like this
          var response_script = object_response.script;

          // And the second one the same way
          var response_div = object_response.div;

          // And then, for example, you can then append that div like this
          $("body").append(response_div);

        }
     });
</script>
```

**Edit changed -> to . as suggested below**

Second edit, it's true that you won't need JSON.parse() under 1 condition, is that you set your headers right `header('Content-type:application/json');` otherwise this technique as suggested in the comments will not work and you will have to use JSON.parse() function

Comment: @user2486 Damn it ! I got mixed up ! changed it now, thanks for the observation !

Comment: @user2486 Only if headers are correctly set as mentioned in my edit but most people forget or do this incorrectly. But good to mention ways

Comment: @user2486 yup, all selectors in jQuery are surrounded by quotes

Answer (score 0):

Use "jQuery.parseHTML()" to parse your string to a valid DOM Element. After this, you can use the ".append()" function to add it to your body.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("html body").append(` to add javascript in body after page load

```js
function oldDivClicked(){
  console.log("old Div Clicked");
}

function changeDiv(){
  $("#mydiv").html('<span onclick="newDivClicked()">New Div: apply newDivClicked()</span>');
  $("html body").append('<script>function newDivClicked(){console.log("new Div Clicked");}<\/script>');
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"><span onclick="oldDivClicked()">Old Div: apply oldDivClicked() </span></div>
<button onclick="changeDiv()">Get New Data</button>
</div>
```

When page load `newDivClicked()` is not present and when you click on `Get New Data` you will also be able to get `newDivClicked()`.

Answer (score 0):

Example of dynamic script and div include:

```
var data = {
  script: "<script type='text\/javascript' >alert('It works')<\/script>",
  div: "<div class='info'>info<\/div>"
};

$('body').append(data.div);
$('head').append(data.script);
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8um4qe8h/1/

P.S. I needed to put escape char to run this example, so that's why data looks ugly

Comment: The `/` [are the only thing you needed to escape](https://jsfiddle.net/c4gbv8k1/), single quotes and `<` don't need to be quoted in a double quoted string.