# Find Address from postcode and editing input form without reloading page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to add some functionality to a register page that I am building.

The functionality is finding an address from a postcode and adding that data to the input form.

I have found a way to do this but there are some issues involved with the way that I am doing it.  At the moment I am using a form with a submit button then using if(isset($_post) which means the page will be reloaded once this submit button is hit which I dont want.

My thinking is that I will need to use some jquery or ajex to do with without reloading the form but honestly I am not sure where to begin.

I have wrote a funtion that returns the data that I need as an array

postcode_api_test.php

```
<?php
function lookuppostcode($postcode)
{
    $postcode = str_replace(" ", "", $postcode);
    $key = 'MY API KEY';
    $request = 'https://api.getAddress.io/v2/uk/' . $postcode . '?api-key=' . $key;
    $response = file_get_contents($request);
    $jsonresponse = json_decode($response, true);
    $returnData = array();

    $returnData['lat'] = $jsonresponse['Latitude'];
    $returnData['lon'] = $jsonresponse['Longitude'];
    $returnData['totalAddresses'] = count($jsonresponse['Addresses']);

    $addressArray = explode(',', $jsonresponse['Addresses'][0]);
    $returnData['locality'] = $addressArray[4];
    $returnData['city'] = $addressArray[5];
    $returnData['county'] = $addressArray[6];

    $returnData['addresses'] = array();

    foreach ($jsonresponse['Addresses'] as $address) {
        $addressArray = explode(',', $address);
        $fullAddress = '';

        foreach ($addressArray as $item) {
            if ($item != ' ') {
                $fullAddress .= $item . ",";
            }
        }
        $fullAddress = trim($fullAddress, ",");
        $returnData['addresses'][] = array(
            'line1' => $addressArray[0],
            'line2' => $addressArray[1],
            'line3' => $addressArray[2],
            'line4' => $addressArray[3],
            'locality' => $addressArray[4],
            'city' => $addressArray[5],
            'county' => $addressArray[6],
            'fullAddress' => $fullAddress,
        );
    }
    return $returnData;
}
?>
```

postcode.php:

```
<?php
include 'postcode_api_test.php';
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "ajex_test.js"> </script>

<form   method="post">
<form method = "post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Entity Type</label>
    <label class="control-label">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" class="form-control" value = "">
    <button class="btn btn-success"  onclick = "postcodelookup()" name = "postcodebtn" id="postcodebtn">  </button>


<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

</form>
</form>
```

I was wondering if anybody has any pointers of how to start this off?

ajax_test.js

```
function postcodelookup($postcode){
    $("#postcodebtn").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "postcodecall.php",
        data:{"postcode":$("#postcode").val},
        success: function(data){

            $("#div1").html(data);

        }
    });
});
```

};

postcodecall.php

```
<?php
include 'postcode_api_test.php';

if(isset($_GET["postcode"])){

$postcode = $_GET["postcode"];
lookuppostcode($postcode);
echo $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: If you don't want to reload the whole page you can do a client-side javascript call to the API url, parse the results with javascript and update the DOM of your page. Look here for example on how to use [ajax with jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: This is along the lines I was thinking but is there a way to do something similar by using the funtion returning the array that I have already have?

Comment: Yes, instead of calling the postcode API from javascript you can call your own page with ajax and inject the response as HTML in your page with something like `$('div#output').html(responseHtml)`

Comment: Example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637762/returning-the-html-from-ajax-call

Comment: Sorry I am not quite getting it at the moment. Im not sure how I am going to get the information form the html page if it hasnt been loaded yet? I will need an onclick to take the postcode entered in the input field to run the funtion to create the array then use ajex to pull the information form the array?

Comment: Yes, you attach a `click` event to the button (make it `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`), call your PHP page with ajax and show the results in a div on your page. See example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

Comment: I was just starting to make my way to something like that .. I have made an edit to the bottom of my question. Is that along the right lines? How to I then pass the parameter to my function to return the correct information?

Comment: The parameter would be `$_GET["postcode"]` in the PHP you call in your ajax. Be aware that instead of `$("findaddress")` it's probably `$(".findaddress")`  (`.` for classes) or `$("#findaddress")` (`#` for IDs)

Comment: @SteveT Thanks for you help but I still can't quite get this correct have have made some edits to my code again .. where am I going wrong here? I am probably way off the mark now.

Comment: Here's another example which actually loads an HTML page below the button: https://js.do/code/310527 . Please consider to check your code for invalid HTML (duplicated tags, unnecessary whitespace, start tags with no matching end tags...)

Comment: @SteveT I managed to get it working (edited code) took a day or two off to look at it with fresh eyes and it all clicked. Is my code something similar to what you had talked about? your comments definatly pointed me in the right direction so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else that comes across this this is my working code any comments please let me know.

I created a page returns the data in json format using the function i created.  Then I created an ajax call to this page which allowed me to access this information without having to reload the main poscode_api page.

There may be a smoother way to do if there is please share. This worked for me and seems fairly straight forward.

Code below:

_test page

postcode.php

```
<?php
include 'postcode_api_test.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "ajex_test.js"> </script>


<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Postcode</label>

    <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" class="form-control" value = "">
    <button  onclick = "postcodelookup()"  name = "postcodebtn" id="postcodebtn">  </button>
    <select name = "postcode_lookup" id = "postcode_lookup" style = "display = hidden;">
    <option value = "Please Select"> </option>
    </select>


    <div>  <input type="text" name="addressline1" id="addressline1" class="form-control" value = ""> <label> Addressline1</div>
    <div>  <input type="text" name="addressline2" id="addressline2" class="form-control" value = ""> <label> Addressline2</div>
    <div>  <input type="text" name="addressline3" id="addressline3" class="form-control" value = ""> <label> Addressline3</div>
    <div>  <input type="text" name="addressline4" id="addressline4" class="form-control" value = ""> <label> Addressline4</div>
    <div>  <input type="text" name="town" id="town" class="form-control" value = ""> <label> town</div>
    <div>  <input type="text" name="county" id="county" class="form-control" value = ""> <label> county</div>


</html>
```

postcodecall.php

```
<?php
include 'postcode_api_test.php';

if (isset($_GET["postcode"]) && $_GET["postcode"] != "") {

    $postcode = $_GET["postcode"];
    $data = lookuppostcode($postcode);
    $fulladdress = array();
    foreach ($data['addresses'] as $address) {
        $fulladdress[] = $address['fullAddress'];
    }

    $jsondata = json_encode($fulladdress);
    echo $jsondata;

}
```

ajax_test.js

```
function postcodelookup($postcode)
{    
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "postcodecall.php",
            data:{postcode: $('#postcode').val()},
            dataType: 'json',

            beforeSend :function()
            {       
                $("#postcode_lookup option:gt(0)").remove(); 
                $('#postcode_lookup').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('#postcode_lookup').show();
                $('#postcode_lookup').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please select your Address");
                alert('Please Select Address from the list - If your address is not here please enter manually. Thanks');
                postcode_dropdown = '';
                $(data).each(function(addressline,fulladdress)
                {      
                fulladdresstrim = fulladdress.replace(/ ,/g, '')


                postcode_dropdown += '<option value = "' + fulladdress+'"> '+ fulladdresstrim +' </option>';                   
                });             
                $('#postcode_lookup').append(postcode_dropdown);        
            },
            error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
                alert('Exception:', exception);
            }

        });

}



    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#postcode_lookup').hide();
        $('#postcode_lookup').on('change',function(){           
            var fulladdress = $(this).val();
            var addressline = fulladdress.split(",");
                $('#addressline1').val(addressline[0]);
                $('#addressline2').val(addressline[1]);
                $('#addressline3').val(addressline[2]);
                $('#town').val(addressline[5]);
                $('#county').val(addressline[6]);

        });
    });
```

postcode_api_test.php

```
<?php


function lookuppostcode($postcode)
{
    $postcode = str_replace(" ", "", $postcode);
    $key = 'MY API CODE';
    $request = 'https://api.getAddress.io/v2/uk/' . $postcode . '?api-key=' . $key;
    $response = file_get_contents($request);
    $jsonresponse = json_decode($response, true);
    $returnData = array();
    $returnData['lat'] = $jsonresponse['Latitude'];
    $returnData['lon'] = $jsonresponse['Longitude'];
    $returnData['totalAddresses'] = count($jsonresponse['Addresses']);
    $addressArray = explode(',', $jsonresponse['Addresses'][0]);
    $returnData['locality'] = $addressArray[4];
    $returnData['city'] = $addressArray[5];
    $returnData['county'] = $addressArray[6];

    $returnData['addresses'] = array();

    foreach ($jsonresponse['Addresses'] as $address) {
        $addressArray = explode(',', $address);
        $fullAddress = '';

        foreach ($addressArray as $item) {

                $fullAddress .= $item . ",";

        }
        $fullAddress = trim($fullAddress, ",");
        $returnData['addresses'][] = array(
            'line1' => $addressArray[0],
            'line2' => $addressArray[1],
            'line3' => $addressArray[2],
            'line4' => $addressArray[3],
            'locality' => $addressArray[4],
            'city' => $addressArray[5],
            'county' => $addressArray[6],
            'fullAddress' => $fullAddress,
        );
    }
    return $returnData;
}
?>
```